# Tree diagram with boxes and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Good day everyone here at TeX.SX. I have been troubled with the following task; I need to create some sort of tree diagram that resembles the accompanied image. I am providing a MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
  text={6.5in,9in},
  centering,
  papersize={8.5in,11in},
  top=1in,
  heightrounded,
  bindingoffset=0.2in%,
  %showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {shape          = rectangle,
                                         draw,
                                         minimum width  = 3cm,
                                         minimum height = 1.2cm,
                                         inner sep      = 3pt,
                                         align          = center,
                                         font           =\footnotesize,
                                         text           = black}]

% the nodes : possible  \newcommand*\dx{5} \newcommand*\dy{2}
    \node[draw=white](0;-1)  at (0,1.5) {\textbf{For Patients Who Opt Out}}; 
    \node(0;0) at (0,0) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.5em]
            \item Counsel on testing benefits
            \item Identify barriers to testing
            \item Provide emotional support
            \item Re-assess intention to test
        \end{itemize}
        }};
    \node[draw=white](0;1)  at (0,-2.5) {\textbf{Specimen Collected}}; 
    \node(0;2) at (0,-3.5) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        Specimen for HIV test collected and if rapid HIV test used (10-20 minute wait for results) as per national algorithm.
        }};  
    \node[draw=white](0;3)  at (0,-5) {\textbf{Further testing performed if indicated}}; 
    \node(0;4) at (0,-6) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        Further testing for positives and inclusive as per national algorithm.
        }};   
    \node(1;1)  at (6, 4) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \textbf{Provider Initiated Counseling Testing}\\ – Routine Offer Average time= 20-30 minutes}};   
    \node(1;2)  at (6, 1) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.5em]
            \item Group Education/HIV Information
            \item HIV test recommended
            \item Confidentiality assured
            \item Consent obtained using ``opt-out'' language
        \end{itemize}
        }};
    \node[draw=white](1;3)  at (6, -1.5) {\textbf{Brief Risk Reduction}}; 
  \node(1;4) at (6,-2.5) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
    Brief Risk-Reduction Counseling may be performed while awaiting rapid test result.
    }}; 
    \node[draw=white](1;5) at (6,-4.25) {\textbf{Provider Gives Test Results}};
    \node(1;6) at (6,-5.25) {%
 \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
    Provider delivers HIV test results and interprets meaning.
    }}; 
    \node[draw=white](1;7) at (6,-7) {\textbf{Post-Test Advice and Referral}};
    \node(1;8) at (6,-8) {%
 \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
    Provider offers information about referrals, and if positive, refers to treatment and care and advises on the importance of disclosure.
    }}; 
    \node(2;1)  at (-6, 4) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \textbf{Voluntary Counseling and Testing}\\ Average time = 1hr.}};
    \node(2;2)  at (-6, 1.35) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.5em]
            \item Client request test
            \item Explanation of HIV/AIDS
            \item Review prevention measures
            \item Consent requested
        \end{itemize}
        }};
    \node[draw=white](2;3)  at (-6, -1) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \textbf{HIV Risk reduction Counseling}}};
    \node(2;4)  at (-6, -2.5) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.5em]
            \item Counselor conducts HIV risk assessment.
            \item Counsellor negotiates personalized risk reduction plan. 
        \end{itemize}
        }};
    \node[draw=white](2;5)  at (-6, -4.5) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \textbf{Counselor Gives Test Results }}};
    \node(2;6)  at (-6, -5.5) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        Counselor delivers HIV test results and interprets meaning
        }};
    \node[draw=white](2;7)  at (-6, -7) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        \textbf{Post-Test Support/Referral}}};
    \node(2;8)  at (-6, -8.25) {%
    \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
        Counselor provides emotional support, reinforces risk-reduction plan, and if positive, referral to treatment and care and reinforces importance of disclosure.
        }};
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (2;2.east) --(-3, 1.35)--(-3, -1.75)--(-0.5, -1.75)  -- (-0.5,-2.25);
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (1;2.west) --(3, 1)--(3, -1.75)--(0.5, -1.75)  -- (0.5,-2.25);
    \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >= 4pt] (2;4.east)-- (0;2.west);
    \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >= 4pt] (1;4.west)-- (0;2.east);
    \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >= -8pt] (1;4.south)-- (1;5.north);
    \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >= -8pt] (1;6.south)-- (1;7.north);
    \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >= -8pt] (2;4.south)-- (2;5.north);
    \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >= -8pt] (2;6.south)-- (2;7.north);                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

My question is, how can I improve the code and if there are better packages to use to achieve the same diagram. I tried to read about the `tree` and `forest` packages but I was unable to use them. So I went kinda brute force on it. I also had a problem with the nodes since the style is applied to all nodes. In other words to make something be unboxed I had to draw it white.

Here is another sample of what I also would like to reproduce, though its not a priority. Colors and the like are irrelevant.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using the `positioning` library to place the nodes and some styles, your code can be simplified:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mybox/.style={
    draw,
    text width=5.7cm,
    anchor=north
  },
  nobox/.style={
    text width=5.7cm,
    align=center,
    anchor=north,
    font=\bfseries
  },
  arr/.style={
    ->,
    line width=0.8pt
  },
  node distance=1cm and 2cm,
  >=latex
]
% The left part
\node[mybox]
  (left1)
  {\textbf{Voluntary Counseling Testing} \\
  Average time=1 hour
  };
\node[mybox,below=of left1]
  (left2)
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
   \end{itemize}
  };  
\node[nobox,below=of left2]
  (left3)
  {HIV Risk reduction Counseling};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of left3]
  (left4)
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
   \end{itemize}
  };  
\node[nobox,below=of left4]
  (left5)
  {Counselor gives test results};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of left5]
  (left6)
  {Some test text goes here for the example};  
\node[nobox,below=of left6]
  (left7)
  {Post-Test Support/Referal};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of left7]
  (left8)
  {Some test text goes here for the example};  

% the middle part
\node[right=of left1,text width=5.5cm] 
  (middle1) {};
\node[nobox,below=2.5cm of middle1]
  (middle2)
  {For Patients Who Opt Out};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of middle2]
  (middle3)
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
   \end{itemize}
  };  
\node[nobox,below=of middle3]
  (middle4)
  {Specimen Collected};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of middle4]
  (middle5)
  {Some test text goes here for the example};  
\node[nobox,below=of middle5,text width=7cm]
  (middle6)
  {Further testing performed if indicated};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of middle6]
  (middle7)
  {Some test text goes here for the example};  

% the right part     
\node[mybox,right=of middle1]
  (right1)
  {\textbf{Provide Initiated Counseling Testing} \\
  Routine Offer Average time=20--20 minutes
  };
\node[mybox,below=of right1]
  (right2)
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
   \end{itemize}
  };  
\node[nobox,below=of right2]
  (right3)
  {HIV Risk reduction Counseling};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of right3]
  (right4)
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
    \item Some text
   \end{itemize}
  };  
\node[nobox,below=of right4]
  (right5)
  {Counselor gives test results};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of right5]
  (right6)
  {Some test text goes here for the example};  
\node[nobox,below=of right6]
  (right7)
  {Counselor gives test results};
\node[mybox,below=0pt of right7]
  (right8)
  {Some test text goes here for the example};  

%the arrows  
\path[arr]
  (left4) edge (left5)
  (left6) edge (left7)
  (right4) edge (right5)
  (right6) edge (right7)
  (left4) edge (middle5.west)
  (right4) edge (middle5.east);
\draw[arr]  
  (left2.east) -- 
  ++(20pt,0pt)  |- 
  ([shift={(-20pt,15pt)}]middle4.north) --
  ([shift={(-20pt,0pt)}]middle4.north);
\draw[arr]  
  (right2.west) -- 
  ++(-20pt,0pt)  |- 
  ([shift={(20pt,15pt)}]middle4.north) --
  ([shift={(20pt,0pt)}]middle4.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the other structure, here's an option using [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) (the picture was too blurry, so I had to guess the desired aspect):

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  frbox/.style={
    draw=cyan!20,
    fill=#1,
    line width=1pt,
    anchor=north,
    text width=4cm,
    minimum height=5ex
  },
  leftn/.style={
    text width=#1,
    draw=cyan,
    double,
    line width=1pt,
    align=left,
    anchor=west,
    minimum height=5ex
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if={level>3}{edge path={}}{},
},
[Some Title
  [Only Child,frbox=cyan
    [Only child,frbox=cyan
      [Left child,name=left,frbox=cyan!30
        [Left two,leftn=3cm
          [Left three,leftn=3.5cm
            [Left four,leftn=4cm
              [Left five,leftn=4.5cm
                [Left six,leftn=5cm
                  [Left seven,leftn=5.5cm,name=last
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Right child,frbox=cyan!30
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw ([xshift=-3pt]left.south) -- ([shift={(-3pt,-5pt)}]last.south west);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]